# Msil metadata for interface includes "Extends : 01000000 [TypeRef]" - what does 01000000 mean?

Tags: .net, cil

I noticed that interface type definition metadata looks like:

```
TypDefName: Interfaces.IMyInterface  (02000003)
Flags     : [Public] [AutoLayout] [Interface] [Abstract] [AnsiClass]  (000000a1)
Extends   : 01000000 [TypeRef]
```

whereas everything else I create e.g. class, enum, struct, has an extends entry that looks like:

```
Extends   : 01000001 [TypeRef] System.Object
```

(where System.Object is replaced with some other class name if the type does not inherit directly):

So, my question is:

Is "01000000" just a magic number that signifies "interface"?  If so, are there other scenarios where similar happens?

**UPDATE**

The entry for System.Object is the same:

```
TypDefName: System.Object  (02000002)
Flags     : [Public] [AutoLayout] [Class] [Serializable] [AnsiClass] [BeforeFieldInit]  (00102001)
Extends   : 01000000 [TypeRef]
```

...actually it is the same for all interfaces:

```
TypDefName: Interfaces.IMyOtherInterface  (02000007)
Flags     : [Public] [AutoLayout] [Interface] [Abstract] [AnsiClass]  (000000a1)
Extends   : 01000000 [TypeRef] 
InterfaceImpl #1 (09000002)
```

This follows what is in the document listed in Hans' answer.

So, even though I can't find the bit that actually says "interfaces and System.Object do not require a TypeDef row", that must be what is happening and so this question is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a 'metadata token', it references an item in the tables in the metadata of the assembly.  The first hex pair indicates the table type, the next 3 pairs is just a sequence number for the table row.  Table 0x01 is the TypeRef table, table 0x02 is the TypeDef table.

This is described well in excruciating detail in Ecma-335, the standards document for the Common Language Infrastructure.

Missed the question, adding: an interface type does not have to inherit anything.  Unlike a class which always derives from System.Object.  Which makes metadata token 0x01000000 likely to mean "nothing".  The actual table entries are however not fixed, you'd normally have to look in the table.  Ildasm does it for you.

Comment: So what does `01000001` mean? Is it a reference to `System.Object`?

Comment: Thank you Hans. I am actually looking at that document now and have been for the last half an hour. I was searching on "extends" instead of TypeRef. I have now found the section that describes the TypeDef table and am therefore accepting your answer. I assume that as the next 3 pairs are zeros this means row zero i.e. "no type reference"? Is that how the Extends entry would show for System.Object as well? I am checking this myself (as soon as I can find a copy of mscorlib.dll on my system).

Comment: Sorry, I mean I will accept it when I can confirm that all the zeros means row zero or no type def (if that is what it means).

Comment: Sorry, I will research when I can confirm that this post was helpful.

Comment: OK, whatever - I'd just like to find the bit that says System.Object and top level interfaces will have zero as their TypeDef row index.  Then I can sleep :).

Comment: Thanks again Hans - I didn't notice you'd updated your answer :).  I appreciate the extra detail.

Comment: Heh - What I wanted is right there in that section.  I am tired and just didn't see it.

Comment: "9. System.Object shall have an Extends value of null" and "13. An Interface never extends another Type - so Extends shall be null"